# how to kill processes in shared host by automatically?

Tags: cron, php, kill

in  shared hosting which allows maximum 25 processes. as it reaches 25 processes , site goes to 500 internal error. in cpanel i manually kill the process one by one . Which script can work to kill all php PID processes automatically? any idea?

Comment: It would be better no limit the creation of processes. Killing stuff will, kill stuff. That will cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `killall` may do what you are asking.

Secondly why are you hitting the process limit? Are your scripts running to long? Are you preforking too much? Is your load that high?

Thirdly wtf is up with that limit? Any site that hits a limit at twenty five similutanious requests will hit problems. Time to look at the hosting options.

Comment: i am not so familiar with that.  the weird thing is that tehre is only this process public_html/old/index.php   only this process creates by time and hits the limit. I tried killall  and used it with cronjob, it did not help.